# В Visual Studio не удается открыть конструктор файла, так как класс этого файла не унаследован от класса, поддерживающего визуальную разработку

Tags: c#, winforms

Во время написания кода перестал работать конструктор форм. При этом сам код прекрасно работает,без каких либо проблем с формой. Если посмотреть справку MSDN,то попадаю сюда https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/43fzdd42(v=vs.110)
Вроде причина понятна,а как ее исправить - нет. Подскажите,что можно сделать?
Изначально у меня консольное приложение,в котором выполняется код,после чего создается и вызывается форма.

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);
```

Самое начала кода формы

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using FormulaAllCode;


namespace Application_12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public char Port1 =(char) 6;
        Graphics Gr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread IR_sens = new Thread(new ThreadStart(IR_Sens));
            IR_sens.Start();
            Thread Music = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Music));
            Music.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Не делайте консольное приложение. Сделайте сразу WinForms.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Нужно именно так. Да и проблема не в этом,так как  изначально все прекрасно работало. А уже в процессе небольших правок кода я видимо что-то не то удалил или добавил. На 99% уверен что ошибка из-за того,что я добавил  новый класс,но как исправить ошибку не удаляя его мне непонятно.

Comment: Покажите файл с `Form1`. Не весь, только начало.

Comment: _конструктор файла_ - имеется в виду дизайнер формы? Класс формы должен быть первым (а лучше - единственным) в файле. Полагаю, вы добавили перед ним другой класс или структуру, или перечисление. На компиляцию это не влияет, но дизайнер при этом не работает. Перенесите тот класс/структуру/перечисление в конец файла, а лучше - в другой файл.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добавил в пример. Не очень пронял про класс. Как его переместить? У меня все классы обьявлены и определены в разных файлах